# Testing that a function will not be called in CoffeeScript (and JS)

Tags: testing, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have this function called `render` that has the following code in CoffeeScript. This is on a Backbone view that only calls the `afterRender` function if one is defined, like shown below:

```
@afterRender() if @afterRender
```

How can I test that afterRender is not being called if it doesn't exist?

Here's the positive test:

```
it 'calls afterRender when defined', ->
  called = false
  @view.afterRender = -> called = true
  @view.render()
  expect(called).toBeTruthy()
```

But everything I tried to come up with a good way to test failed me.

I am using sinon.js, so I can use its spies, mocks and stubs if you think that it would help.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `@afterRender() if @afterRender` line is in the `render` method?

Comment: Hey @TrevorBurnham, sorry for omitting this info. Yes, it is!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [mock](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks) to test both of your cases—that it's called once, in the first case (what you're currenlty manually doing with the `called` variable), and that it's never called in the second:

First case:

```
sinon.mock(@view).expects('afterRender').once()
@view.render()
```

Second case:

```
sinon.mock(@view).exepcts('afterRender').never()
@view.render()
```

Comment: I tried that before. I get `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property afterRender as function`. Apparently I cannot have expectation on a function that doesn't exist (and the test needs it to not exist)

Comment: In that case, why not just test that `@view.afterRender` is `undefined`? I would imagine, however, that you're better off always defining the method and then not calling it unless you need to (just seems like a better design to me).

Comment: Actually, I guess that won't test what you want to test (which is if the function is called, not that it's undefined, even though they're equivalent). In that case, can't you use the same `called` test you set up and check for that it's false instead of truthy? I still think it's a bad idea to leave the function undefined (see my previous comment).